# Clear previous output of widget every time it runs

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

I would like to clear the previous output when the widget is rerun.

for example

```
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

import ipywidgets as widgets
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

```
button = widgets.Button(description='RUN',button_style='info')

def on_button_clicked(b):

    # DO SOMETHING #

    out = widgets.Output()
    out.clear_output(wait=True)
    out.append_stdout(f'Ran at {datetime.now()}')
    display(out)

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
widgets.VBox([button])
```

Every time i click on the `RUN` button it "appends" the print statement

I also tried this:

```
button = widgets.Button(description='RUN',button_style='info')

def on_button_clicked(b):

    # DO SOMETHING #

    out = widgets.Output()
    out.clear_output(wait=True)
    with out:
        print(f'Ran at {datetime.now()}')
    display(out)

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
widgets.VBox([button])
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'button' is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

import ipywidgets as widgets
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


button = widgets.Button(description='RUN',button_style='info')

out = widgets.Output() 

@out.capture(clear_output=True)
def on_button_clicked(b):
    # DO SOMETHING #
    print ( f'Ran at {datetime.now()}')


button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
widgets.VBox([button])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're running ipython 3.8... that's 5 years old. I strongly recommend upgrading to a later version, but totally understand that this is not always possible depending on time and resources.

Here's the documentation for the ipython 3.x display widget:
https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.display.html#functions

Try this:

```py
from IPython.display import clear_output
import ipywidgets as widgets
from datetime import datetime

button = widgets.Button(description='RUN',button_style='info')

def on_button_clicked(b):
    # DO SOMETHING #
    print(f'Ran at {datetime.now()}')

    # This will clear the cell output the NEXT time the button is pressed
    clear_output(wait=True)

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
widgets.VBox([button])
```

There have been some reports of "shaking" in the notebook when `print()` is used. If you notice this, try using `print('message', flush=True)` instead.